# Ionic 6 - Issues with button press in blue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I am using Ionic 6 and I have a button with a class:

```
  .mybutton {
    --background: #f39200;
    --color: white;
  }
```

When I press on the button on my mobile it goes blue.

I need to change that to another color.

I've tried:

```
.mybutton:hover,
.mybutton:active {
   // another color
}
```

It's still blue.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to use another CSS variable.

try --ripple-color, I think it may help you.

Comment: ion-button:hover {
    --background: #f39200;
    --ripple-color: #ff0000;
    --ripple-color: #ff0000;
  }

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need to set it on hover.

Comment: I took off the :hover and I can still see the blue when I press down the button :(